# How to show the xcodebuild command line from xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build a working simulator build from xcodebuild. Compilation works but the final product won't run on the simulator when installed via WaxSim. If I build through the Xcode GUI then the final product installs without issue from WaxSim.

My question is, how can I see the **exact** xcodebuild command line that xcode is using to build a working simulator build. I just need to copy that into my shell script but it's proving elusive. I did a find in the build logs from xcode but there's no mention of xcodebuild there.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Xcode itself doesn't invoke `xcodebuild` during the build process. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010062/xcodebuild-simulator-or-device) has more information on executing `xcodebuild` to build for the simulator.

Comment: Yeah, it all looks sane to me. 

xcodebuild -target "Acceptance Tests" -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 build. The final product just doesn't install and is about half the size of the one xcode is building.