# How can I see log of commands Xcode executed when I press `build` on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I want to see the commands Xcode executed when I press "Build" on Xcode.
Those commands should be like `xcodebuild` and such.

I tried to find it at Xcode > View > Navigators > Show Report Navigator ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060898/xcode-how-to-see-build-command-and-log)), but I can not find the keyword `xcodebuild` inside. I want to see the parameters Xcode used for xcodebuild.

Am I able to do that?

Comment: did you find solution for it?

Comment: No, I gave up. But this feature should be useful.

Comment: @iKushal The solution would be to examine xcodebuild documentation to figure out what commands it offers that would perform the task you're doing

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Xcode doesn't use `xcodebuild` in the build process. (If you think about it, the `xcodebuild` command is user-facing and part of the Xcode command-line tools, but those aren't required to be present to build and/or run something in it.) Here's the entirety of [this very short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14574625/3167040):

> You can't. Xcode itself doesn't invoke xcodebuild during the build process. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010062/xcodebuild-simulator-or-device) has more information on executing xcodebuild to build for the simulator.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping I could script the repetitive parts of my develop test cycle.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat This answer doesn't necessarily prevent you from doing something like that

Comment: Good to know. Now I need to remember how to find out the underlying commands (I’ve only been playing with iOS development very occasionally).